# Disable buttons but keep style

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to disable buttons but keep the default style? Not have them greyed out? currently, the buttons are disabled correctly but are shown as greyed out. I have found a similar question however they were using jQuery and I need to use vanilla JavaScript.

```
function disableAnswers() {
    for (let i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
        answers[i].disabled = true;
    }
    nextQ.classList.remove('hidden');
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to mislead your users that the button works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle this with simple CSS:

```css
button:disabled {
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<button disabled>Button</button>
```

Comment: Wow, so simple! I love it.

Comment: The `border-color` and `background-color` still seem different on Chrome.

Comment: I guess they can be set to `initial` too if needed..